# Getting drop down menu links in a full width css menu drop down to line up with their parent element

Tags: html, css

[image]I have a navigation which uses a full width drop down sub-menu (the about drop down) but I am struggling to align the links within the submenu centeraly underneath their parent. I also need this to be responsive so the sub-links stay central no matter the view width.

Could anyone help me by telling me where I am going wrong or what I would need to do to achieve this effect?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```css
.navigation--main li:hover>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.navigation--main li ul {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 114px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.navigation--main li ul li {
  padding: 1.5em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation--container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/Group 85.svg" alt="ORRAA Logo" class="homeLogo" height="78.93" width="260" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation--main">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href=""></a>Ocean risk</li>
          <li>
            <a href=""></a>About ORRAA</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Governance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navigation--social-icons">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/facebook.svg" alt="facebook"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/instagram.svg" alt="instagram"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/Path 22.svg" alt="twitter"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you explain more how the end result should look like.

Comment: please see image above

Comment: so you need to have a result like as in the above photo ?

Comment: Yes thats correct. I want the links to align to their parent.

Answer (score 2):

you can change in css file.. hope this solution help you.

```
.navigation--main li:hover>ul {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  width: calc(100vw - 112px);
}
.navigation--main li:hover>ul li{
  margin-left:20px;
}

ul.navigation--main li ul {
  background: $brand-sky-blue;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.navigation--main li ul li {
  padding:10px;
}
```

this is example for reference: [codepen.io/arpita1030/pen/pMLQME](https://codepen.io/arpita1030/pen/pMLQME)

Comment: also add this css file for perfect look of links  ```.navigation--main li:hover>ul li{
  margin-left:20px;
} ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this did not work as i need the sub-menu postioned underneath the navigation container with the links positioned underneath their parent.

Comment: can u send the screen shot of what you want ? @MatthewProctor

Comment: Please see image above

Comment: Thanks for trying but thats the point im already at, the links center screen instead of centering to the about parent.

Comment: [https://codepen.io/arpita1030/pen/pMLQME ] this is example i hope this example help you @MatthewProctor

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood correctly, but here is my proposal

```
.navigation--main li:hover > ul {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: static;
}
```

Now the div in question appears right underneath `About` navigation link and moves rest of the elements further down.

Comment: I have added more css to give a better representation, many thanks.